# XSL to Xml with sorting error

Tags: xml, xslt

> **Here is my xml data source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
<quarter qt="3">
<PostCode>
<Code abbr="2000"></Code>
<Learner>1,116</Learner>
<P1>99993</P1>
<P2>402</P2>
<Unrestricted>10,137</Unrestricted>
<ClassC>11564</ClassC>
<ClassLR>69</ClassLR>
<ClassMR>74</ClassMR>
<ClassHR>108</ClassHR>
<ClassHC>43</ClassHC>
<ClassMC>4</ClassMC>
<ClassR>976</ClassR>
</PostCode>
<PostCode>
<Code abbr="2000"></Code>
<Learner>3</Learner>
<P1>11</P1>
<P2>3000000000000</P2>
<Unrestricted>14</Unrestricted>
<ClassC>20</ClassC>
<ClassLR>0</ClassLR>
<ClassMR>1</ClassMR>
<ClassHR>1</ClassHR>
<ClassHC>0</ClassHC>
<ClassMC>0</ClassMC>
<ClassR>3</ClassR>
</PostCode>
<PostCode>
<Code abbr="2006"></Code>
<Learner>389</Learner>
<P1>103</P1>
<P2>177</P2>
<Unrestricted>2,682</Unrestricted>
<ClassC>3,242</ClassC>
<ClassLR>14</ClassLR>
<ClassMR>34</ClassMR>
<ClassHR>37</ClassHR>
<ClassHC>9</ClassHC>
<ClassMC>0</ClassMC>
<ClassR>317</ClassR>
</PostCode>
</quarter>
</data>
```

And here is my xsl source

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="Code"/>
<xsl:param name="quarter"/>
<xsl:param name="sortBy" select="'ClassC'"/>
<xsl:param name="order" select="'descending'"/>

<xsl:template match="data">
<data>
<quarter>

<xsl:apply-templates select="quarter[@qt=$quarter]">
</xsl:apply-templates>
</quarter>
</data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="quarter">
<xsl:apply-templates select="PostCode/Code[@abbr=$Code]" >
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Code">
<xsl:for-each select="..">
<xsl:sort select="ClassC" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
//here is my key code
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I can not sort by the "ClassC" and the result is

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data><quarter><PostCode>
<Code abbr="2000"/>
<Learner>1,116</Learner>
<P1>99993</P1>
<P2>402</P2>
<Unrestricted>10,137</Unrestricted>
<ClassC>11564</ClassC>
<ClassLR>69</ClassLR>
<ClassMR>74</ClassMR>
<ClassHR>108</ClassHR>
<ClassHC>43</ClassHC>
<ClassMC>4</ClassMC>
<ClassR>976</ClassR>
</PostCode><PostCode>
<Code abbr="2000"/>
<Learner>3</Learner>
<P1>1111111111111</P1>
<P2>3</P2>
<Unrestricted>14</Unrestricted>
<ClassC>200000000000</ClassC>
<ClassLR>0</ClassLR>
<ClassMR>1</ClassMR>
<ClassHR>1</ClassHR>
<ClassHC>0</ClassHC>
<ClassMC>0</ClassMC>
<ClassR>3</ClassR>
</PostCode>
</quarter>
</data>
```

Hi everyone, I was asked to order the xml data by=Class C and do other things later.
But I met a very strage problem!
Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Because I dont know hot to solve this?It is quite werid!

Comment: Could you please reduce your XML to the parts where a problem occurs? WHAT problem actually occurs? What software is being used... This question is not clear at all!

Answer (score 0):

You have not well explained which result you want respectively which elements you want to sort, if you want to sort the `PostCode` elements then here is an example doing that, simply by making sure the `xsl:sort` is used for an `xsl:apply-templates` on the `PostCode` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="Code">2000</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="quarter">3</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="sortBy" select="'ClassC'"/>
    <xsl:param name="order" select="'descending'"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <data>
            <quarter>             
                <xsl:apply-templates select="quarter[@qt=$quarter]"/>                
            </quarter>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="quarter">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PostCode[Code[@abbr=$Code]]" >
            <xsl:sort select="Code/*[local-name() = $sortBy]" order="{$order}" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKS, result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
   <quarter>
      <PostCode>
         <Code abbr="2000"/>
         <Learner>1,116</Learner>
         <P1>99993</P1>
         <P2>402</P2>
         <Unrestricted>10,137</Unrestricted>
         <ClassC>11564</ClassC>
         <ClassLR>69</ClassLR>
         <ClassMR>74</ClassMR>
         <ClassHR>108</ClassHR>
         <ClassHC>43</ClassHC>
         <ClassMC>4</ClassMC>
         <ClassR>976</ClassR>
      </PostCode>
      <PostCode>
         <Code abbr="2000"/>
         <Learner>3</Learner>
         <P1>11</P1>
         <P2>3000000000000</P2>
         <Unrestricted>14</Unrestricted>
         <ClassC>20</ClassC>
         <ClassLR>0</ClassLR>
         <ClassMR>1</ClassMR>
         <ClassHR>1</ClassHR>
         <ClassHC>0</ClassHC>
         <ClassMC>0</ClassMC>
         <ClassR>3</ClassR>
      </PostCode>
   </quarter>
</data>
```